# sqlite in java web application memory use

Tags: java, sqlite, memory, jvm

I am using sqlite database memory model in my Java Web application to support some features.

```
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
              connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

but I do not know, how many much used momery is used by sqlite and does it use JVM memory or system memory?

Answer (score 0):

[PRAGMA page_count](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_count) tells you how large the database is.

The SQLite library itself is not written in Java, so it does not use JVM memory.

Comment: thinks for your answer